# Find rows in Pandas dataframe based on conditional group from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a repeat question or for the poor heading, I haven't been able to properly articulate in one line what I'm trying to find in a generic sense, so using the example below for what I'm trying to do.

I want to attain certain rows from a dataframe based on a min and max value from another dataframe. The min and max values are conditional on the group assigned:

```
data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'John', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Tim', 'Tim'],
    'Salary': [18000, 20000, 15000, 35000, 12000, 30000]
} 

boundary = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Sam', 'Tim'],
    'Min': [19000, 18000, 10000],
    'Max': [21000, 30000, 32000]
}


data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Salary'])
boundary = pd.DataFrame(boundary, columns = ['Name', 'Min', 'Max'])
```

I want the result to be the below dataframe, where only the rows from the data df above the max and below the min from the boundary df are kept.

```
    Name    Salary
0   John    18000
2   Sam     15000
3   Sam     35000
```

I've been able to do this with a single min/max, but can't quite figure it out with the groups involved, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge in combination with query

```
data.merge(boundary, how="left", on="Name").query("Salary > Max or Salary < Min")[["Name", "Salary"]]
```

Comment: Nice way to avoid the extra line of code I was using.

Comment: Can't yet comment on your post (need 50 reputation), but good answer as well with a lot of links to documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I have to start using `query` and `eval` more often. The [`df.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) alternative of your method would be even shorter: `data[data.merge(boundary, how="left", on="Name").eval("Salary > Max or Salary < Min")]`. Performance seems to be quite similar for both these methods, and mine as well.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

- First, use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get `Min` and `Max` attached.
- Next, combine [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with the unary operator (`~`), so as to invert the result (i.e. we are looking for all values outside of the boundaries).
- Finally, keep only columns `Name` and `Salary`, achieving this by using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), or you could use [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) as well.

```
res = data.merge(boundary, on='Name', how='left')
res = res.loc[~res.Salary.between(res.Min, res.Max, 
                                  inclusive='both'), ['Name', 'Salary']]
print(res)

   Name  Salary
0  John   18000
2   Sam   15000
3   Sam   35000
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!